# Changing the `chosen` JavaScript options for some selects, without destroying it first

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I am using the excellent `chosen` `jQuery` Plugin, and want to have some selects be handeled differently from others.

The styles I use from an external source (similar to Bootstrap) already make use of chosen and set it up in a general fashion for all select elements:

That's their code (in main.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10
  });
});
```

Now I want to adapt the style for some specifically marked selects. Here's my code (in my-addons.js), which is loaded after the main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".chosen-allow-single-deselect").chosen("destroy");

    $(".chosen-allow-single-deselect").chosen({
        disable_search_threshold: 10,
        allow_single_deselect: true
    });
});
```

Although this works fine so far, I feel that the destroying and recreation of chosen is overkill.

**Is there a way to change the chosen options after initial creation?**